# AngularJS Track By $index w/ filtered and un-filtered list

Tags: javascript, angularjs

So I am building out 2 separate lists in the view based on the same data.

```
<md-list-item md-no-ink ng-repeat="item in $ctrl.items | filter: {custom: '!'} track by $index">

<md-list-item md-no-ink ng-repeat="item in $ctrl.items | filter: {custom: '!!'} track by $index">
```

You can see that one list is for `custom` items. 
So my question is, is there anything that can be done in order to solve the issue of `$index:0` referring to the first element in my `models-data`?

This becomes troublesome because my `custom` list allows CRUD functionality in the view but the `$index:0` in my `custom` list is not necessarily truly `$ctrl.items[0]`.

My current solution is to filter my data into 2 separate collections. Then use each collection for its respected list.

I am just curious if there was any way to do this while maintaining a single array of data.

Comment: use `$ctrl.items[$index + 1]`

Comment: what `custom` has, `0`' and `1`? Not understood completely, what exactly the question is..

Comment: @SachilaRanawaka what if the filter skips more than one or none at all. If so `$ctrl.items[$index + 1]` would not work. Would it?

Comment: Don't use index to reference objects in your crud operations. Pass whole object to controller and do any indexing of master array there

Comment: @PankajParkar, custom is a property that is a boolean, but it may not be present. That is why I am doing '!' and '!!'.

Comment: @lealceldeiro You are correct, his answer does not solve this problem of mine.

Comment: @charlietfl This is possible, but then for every crud operation I would have to search through my collection for this object.

Comment: @Summy that is a trivial operation and can be simplified with one helper function

Comment: @charlietfl is right, it would be of complexity `O(n)`.

Comment: @charlietfl I agree it is very trivial. But could be troublesome for large data sets and also I'd much rather just split my collection into 2 and then have direct access to each through $index.

Answer (score 0):

Since filters return new arrays any filter index will not be representative of index for same item in original array.

For that reason if you need to index an item in original array just pass whole the object into any crud operations and do the indexing in controller using `Array#indexOf()`

Example to delete item:

```
<div ng-repeat="item in $ctrl.items| filter:someFilter track by $index">
   <button ng-click="$ctrl.deleteItem(item)">Delete:</button>
</div>
```

Controller

```
ctrl.deleteItem = function(item){
   let idx = ctrl.items.indexOf(item);
   // make sure it actually exists
   if(idx >-1 ){
      // remove from array
      ctrl.items.splice(idx, 1)
   }
}
```